# .post loads undefined images

Tags: jquery, mysql, onload

I'm developing a website, now I make a query to a mysql db that returns correctly everything I need.
It returns 4 rows with different images, like:
madrid,spain, image1
madrid,spain, image2
madrid,spain, image3
madrid,spain, image4
But it sets:
madrid,spain, image4
madrid,spain, image4
madrid,spain, image4
madrid,spain, image4
I think it goes with the next loop before setting img.src

```
$.post("include/query.php", {do: "q", q: str}, function(data){ 
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            (...)
                $imageid = data[i]['imageid'];
                var image = new Array();
                image[i] = data[i]['image'];
                $desc_cn = data[i]['idescription'];

                if(image[i]!=null){
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function () {
                       $( "#images_preview" ).append(""+
                            "<div class=\"container\">"+
                                "<div class=\"image\">"+
                                "<img src=\""+image[i]+"\" alt=\""+image[i]+"\">"+
                            "</div>");
                    }
                    img.src = image[i]+"?_="+(new Date().getTime());
                }
        };
    }, "json");
```

What do you think?

**SOLVED**

Well, Regent gave me the idea to use a function. And that's what I did..
I put the whole Image thing in a function that I call each loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            if (image[i]){
                newImage(str, imageid[i], image[i], desc_es[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `.onload` function is executed asynchronously. At the moment of its execution `i` already equals to _4_. That is the problem. Well, as I read code, it turns out that `image` Array is created **inside** loop. What is the point of this?

Comment: I agree with the array.. So, you suggest I should create _i_ different Images? How could I do it?

Comment: Well, this is what I can suggest as solution for your problem: [example of idea](http://jsfiddle.net/jy4jx6rh/1/).